# Cannot extract confidence level from StanfordOpenIE

Tags: stanford-nlp

Was using StanfordOepnIE for my professor on a research project.

I can successfully extract the triples by using OpenIE annotator from the Standford NLP server.

However, the confidence score was not returned with the requested json as it was shown on the website
https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html.

Apparently it seemed like that was not being implemented yet by the Stanford people.

Anyone has solution to the problem or have alternative python library that I can to extract both the expected output with its confidence level from the Stanford OpenIE?

Answer (score 0):

The text output has the confidences. We can add the confidences into the json for future versions.